# Использование тернарных операций

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Задание такое:

> Используя тернарную операцию `1?2:3`
> и необходимые арифметические операции, составить программу, выполняющую следующие действия
> `z = x-y, если x>y и z= y-x+1, если x<=y`.

Я могу только минимум найти. А как задавать операции?
Жду подсказок, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 z = x > y ? x - y : y - x + 1;
```

*PS Не понял в каком месте возникла проблема.*

Comment: проблема в том, что торможу с алгоритмированием.
с ходу только выведу минимальное из них.
А вот так - не допёрло сразу:)

Answer (score 5):

Например так:

```
z = ( x > y ) ? ( x - y ) : ( y - x + 1 );
```

Можно так:

```
z = ( x - y ) * ( ( x > y ) ? 1 : -1 ) + ( ( x > y ) ? 0 : 1 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Раз пошла такая пьянка (имею в виду ответ [[@GLmonster](/users/4139/glmonster)](/users/4139/glmonster)), внесу свои 5 копеек

```
((z = x - y) > 0) || (z = 1 - z);
```

Comment: а порядок вычисления операндов вокруг `||` определен?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сначала вычисляется левая часть, если она false, то правая. Во всяком случая,  в gcc все работает.

Comment: мне еще учиться и учиться, я знаю синтаксис, но не умею так вертеть=)

Comment: И не вертите, это все так, пустая скиллометрия.

Comment: @avp, бебебе. Есно, это забава и в реальной программе я так писать не буду. Может, Вы свой вариант предложите?

Comment: Конечно забава. По моему тут уже все перебрали. Но, плюсую. (особенно z = 1-z понравилось !)

Comment: это чем-то близко к куайнам.  
бесполезная головоломка.

Answer (score 3):

А как вам такой нестандартный вариант?

```
x>y && z=x-y;
x>y || z=y-x+1;
```

Конечно, тернарной операции тут нет, но её и так уже привели. В крайнем случае, если необходимо, можно сделать 1? 2 : 3; как написал [[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev).

После первого комментария появились ещё идеи:

Во-первых, можно и без скобок:

```
x>y && z=x-y || z=y-x+1
```

Можно если переписать и так:

```
x<=y && z=y-x+1 || z=x-y
```

Только эти примеры будут работать корректно, потому что, если x>y, то z никогда не будет равно 0, и не будет проблем с тем, что начнёт выполняться второе условие, если первое истинно. В других случаях можно легко допустить ошибку.

Comment: Тогда уж:

    ( ( x > y ) && ( z = x - y ) ) || ( z = y - x + 1 )

Comment: Без скобок лучше не писать... Вдруг в каком-то языке Приоритет(||) больше чем Приоритет(&&)...

Да и лишний раз вспоминать о приоритетах - не есть гуд...

Comment: вы и прям монстр.  
богат не русский язык, а C++ =)

Comment: >Без скобок лучше не писать... Вдруг в каком-то языке Приоритет(||) больше чем Приоритет(&&)...

 По правилам информатики у логического И приоритет выше, чем у ИЛИ. Логическое И по-другому называют логическим умножением, а ИЛИ - логическим сложением. Даже по правилам математики получается так же. Не думаю, что какой-то язык попрёт против этих правил. Тем более, мы говорим про C\C++.

>Да и лишний раз вспоминать о приоритетах - не есть гуд...

 Да и вообще, использовать такой нестандартный вариант не есть гуд. По сравнению с его использованием приоритеты это уже мелочь.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x, y, z;
...
if (x > y) {
    z = x - y;
} else {
    z = y - x + 1;
}
1 ? 2 : 3;
```

Comment: сказано ведь -- с тернарными операциями.

Comment: А у меня разве без тернарных?